# Is it safe to read and write to an array at different positions from multiple threads in C with phtreads?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Let's suppose that there are two threads, A and B. There is also a shared array: `float X[100]`.

Thread A writes to the array one element at a time in order, every 10 steps it updates a shared variable `index` (in a safe way) that indicates the current index, and it also sends a signal to thread B.
As soon as thread B receives the signal, it reads `index` in a safe way, and then proceed to read the elements of `X` until position `index`.

Is it safe to do this? Thread A really updates the array or just a copy in cache?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to do this?

Provided your data modification is rendered safe and protected by critical sections, locks or whatever, this kind of access is perfectly safe for what concerns hardware access.

> Thread A really updates the array or just a copy in cache?

Just a copy in cache. Most caches are presently *write-back* and just write data back to memory when a line is ejected from the cache if it has been modified. This largely improves memory bandwidth, especially in a multicore context.

BUT all happens *as if* the memory had been updated.

For shared memory processors, there are generally cache coherency protocols (except in some processors for real time applications). The basic idea of these protocols is that a *state* is associated with every cache line.
State describes informations concerning the line in the cache of the different processors.
These states indicate, for instance, if the line is only present in the current cache, or is shared by several caches, in sync with memory, invalid... See for instance [this description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) of the popular MESI cache coherence protocol.

So what happens, when a cache line is written and is also present in another processor?
Thanks to the state, the cache knows that one or more other processor also have a copy of the line and it will send an invalidate signal. The line will be invalidated in the other caches and when they want to read or write it, they have to reload its content. Actually, this reload will be served by the cache that has the valid copy to limit memory accesses.

This way, whilst data is only written in the cache, the behavior is similar to a situation where data would have been written to memory.

BUT, despite the fact that functionally the hardware will ensure correctness of the transfer, one must be take into account the cache existence, to avoid performances degradation.
Assume cache A is updating a line and cache B is reading it. Whenever cache A writes, the line in cache B is invalidated. And whenever cache B wants to read it, if the line has been invalidated, it must fetch it from cache A. This can lead to many transfers of the line between the caches and render inefficient the memory system.

So concerning your example, probably 10 is not a good idea, and you should use informations on the caches to improve your exchanges between sender and receiver.

For instance, if you are on a pentium with 64 bytes cache lines, you should declare X as

```
_Alignas(64) float X[100];
```

This way the starting address of `X` will be a multiple of 64 and fit cache lines boundaries.  The `_Alignas` quaiifier exists since C17, and by including stdalign.h, you can also use similarly `alignas(64)`. Before C17, there were several extensions in most compilers in order to have an aligned placement.
And of course, you should indicate process B to read data only when a full 64 bytes line (16 floats) has been written.

This way, when thread  B accesses the data, the cache line will not be modified any longer by thread A and only one initial transfer between caches A and B Will take place. This reduction in the number of  transfers between the caches may have a significant impact on performances depending on your program.

Comment: > *Whenever cache A writes, the line in cache B is invalidated.* I don't think that's a problem here. A is writing entries into a buffer (circular?) at an incrementing index. The risk is that as B consumes up to the index, A places more items into the buffer ahead of the index. But those bits are intended for B; it's quite okay that B's cache is picking them up ahead of time.

Comment: According to OP, all is safe in terms of software and that is something that is not really difficult to implement in this simple producer consumer scheme. But I wanted to sensibilize OP to the problem of false sharing. Even if all is safe in terms of SW, and that thread B properly reads a chunk while thread A fills the next, if the buffers for successive  chunks share a cache line,  the transfer can be very inefficient because of the cache coherence protocol.

Comment: I don't believe it; there is no coherence issue if A is only reading what B is writing. Just A has to pick up the updates from B.  The inefficiency is just double flushing; if B puts an item, signals and then puts another item, and signals, and those items are in the same cache line, two updates will take place instead of one. But that is not solved by putting items into separate cache lines. If B is able to plae multiple items and increment index by several positions at once, that largely takes care of it.

Comment: @kaz There is a coherence problem if two threads read and write the same cache line and it impacts performances. Compile [this code](http://codepad.org/L4osaF2p). It just creates 2 threads: One writes a part of an array and the other reads another disjoint part of the array. And it measures cycles per point if these parts are either in the same or in different cache lines. On my computer,  there is a systematic 2--4 slow down with a false sharing. Must be compiled with gcc on a pentium, as it uses intrinsics to read cycle count.

Comment: That's just it, there is no "false sharing"; A and B are **actually** sharing. All the items put into the buffer by B are to be consumed by A. The observed slow-down is necessary because the items are traveling from one processor to another; it's a form of communication which has overhead; it is not comparable to A and B working independently on adjacent array cells, where the *de facto* communication that occurs is just an unwanted byproduct of proximity.

Comment: When a thread is filling a chunk, while another thread is reading *another* chunk, and there is an interaction between them at the cache level, I think it is a form of a false sharing. But, if you prefer another term, you are welcome. The important is that we can probably agree on the fact that OP should align its transfers to cache lines to improve performances.

Answer (score 2):

Every sane way of one thread sending a signal to another provides the assurance that anything written by a thread before sending a signal is guaranteed to be visible to a thread after it receives that signal. So as long as you sent the signal through some means that provided this guarantee, which they pretty much all do, you are safe.

Note that attempting to use a condition variable without a predicate protected by a mutex is *not* a sane way of one thread sending a signal to another! Among other things, it doesn't guarantee that the thread that you think received the signal actually received the signal. You do need to make sure the thread that does the reads in fact received the very signal sent by the thread that does the writes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a variable to that tracks readiness to read the index, the variable is protected by a mutex and the signalling is done via a pthread condition variable that thread B waits on under the mutex, then yes.

If you're using POSIX signals, then I believe you need a synchronization mechanism on top of that. Writing to an atomic variable with `memory_order_release` in thread A, and reading it with `memory_order_acquire` in thread B should guarantee in the most lightweight fashion that writes in A preceding the write to the atomic should be visible in B after it has read the atomic.

For best performance, the array sharing should be also done in such a way that the shared parts of the array do not cross cache-line boundaries (or else you're performance might degrade due to false sharing).